# groupby to check each of their date in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table `ISIN_TBL` which has two fields `IDENTIFIER` and `ALLT_DATE` which are of datatype `varchar` and `Date` respectively.

There are many `ALLT_DATE` for each `IDENTIFIER` in the table. Normally for each `IDENTIFIER` the `ALLT_DATE` should be the same. But just to confirm i want to write a sql query to list `IDENTIFIER` which has has different `ALLT_DATE`.

I want to modify my below sql query:

```
Select count(*), IDENTIFIER, ALLT_DATE 
from ISIN_TBL
group by IDENTIFIER, ALLT_DATE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to get the exceptsion

```
Select IDENTIFIER 
from ISIN_TBL
group by IDENTIFIER
having MIN(ALLT_DATE) <> MAX(ALLT_DATE);
```

If you want the list of dates -- and it is not too long -- you can use `LISTAGG()`:

```
Select IDENTIFIER, LISTAGG(ALLT_DATE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ALLT_DATE) 
from ISIN_TBL
group by IDENTIFIER
having MIN(ALLT_DATE) <> MAX(ALLT_DATE);
```

Or if there are lots of rows, uses `SELECT DISTINCT` to get distinct values:

```
Select IDENTIFIER, LISTAGG(ALLT_DATE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ALLT_DATE) 
from (SELECT DISTINCT IDENTIFIER, ALLT_DATE
      FROM ISIN_TBL
     ) t
group by IDENTIFIER
having MIN(ALLT_DATE) <> MAX(ALLT_DATE);
```

Comment: second and third query gives error on first line as  FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @Symonds . . . I don't know why my fingers sometimes type `list_agg` instead of `listagg`.